# finding +- 1 with regex python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a table like this:

```
    name      ...
0   AB1
1   AB2
2   AB3
3   AB4
5   CD1
...
... AB99
...
```

I want to match rows where the first 2 alphabets are the same and the number differs by +- 1. However, the smallest number is 1 and the biggest is 99.

How can I do this with regex?

example:

1. If I want results for AB1, I should get only AB2
2. If I want results for AB3, I should get AB2 and AB4

Comment: regex cannot perform arithmetic

Comment: It’ll be helpful if you can add your expected output.

Comment: @anubhava what about loading the pattern beforehand?

Comment: @Nk03 I have just added some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first extract the numbers and convert the dtype:

```
# I am not v.good with regex so may be this part can be done better but idea is below
u = (df['name'].str.extract('(?P<name1>\D+)(?P<Num>\d+)').astype({"Num":int})
     .join(df[['name']]).sort_values(['name1','Num']))

print(u)

  name1  Num name
0    AB    1  AB1
1    AB    2  AB2
2    AB    3  AB3
3    AB    4  AB4
5    CD    1  CD1
```

Once this dataframe is ready, you can add a pandas function using shift:

```
def fun(inp,dataframe):
    c = dataframe['name'].eq(inp)
    g = dataframe.loc[c,'name1']
    v = dataframe[dataframe['name1'].isin(g)]
    c1 = (c.shift()|c.shift(-1))
    return v.loc[c1,'name']
```

---

Sample Runs:

```
print(fun('AB1',u))
print("----------------")
print(fun("AB3",u))

1    AB2
Name: name, dtype: object
----------------
1    AB2
3    AB4
Name: name, dtype: object
```